# Select() is not coming out in client side

Tags: sockets

I have written one client socket program using linux sockets only. Here is the information giving picture what I am doing in my program

1. Creating the socket
2. Making connection with server socket
3. assigning that socket to read set and exception set for select.
4. using the select method giving the timeout value NULL in a separate thread

Server is running in one external device.

this program is working fine for reading and all.. Now I am facing problem when I unplug the power cable of that device.

I assumed that when we remove the power cable of the device all the sockets will abruptly closed and connected client sockets will get read event. when we try to read we receive number of bytes read as zero that means connection closed by server.

But in my program when I unplug the power cable of the device, Here in my client program select is not coming out means client socket is not getting any event. I don't understand why..

Any suggestion will be appreciated on how we can come to know that connection is closed by server or any information on whats the sockets behaviour when shutting down the power supply.

I need your help, its very critical.

thank you.

Comment: Note that `select(2)`is not a method, but a syscall. And using `poll(2)` is probably better. The sockets, if they are TCP/IP ones, won't be closed abruptly; the IP standards mandate a macroscopic delay (perhaps minutes). Please show your code for further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a remote machine is suddenly cut off the network (network cable unplug or power loss), there is no way it can inform the other side of the connection about that. What is more the client side that performs only reads from a half-open socket (like in your case) won't be able to detect this either.

The only way to know about a connection loss is to to send a packet. Since all data being sent should be acknowledged by the other side, TCP on a client computer will keep retrying to send an unconfirmed portion of data till the number of attempts is exhausted. Then a `ETIMEDOUT` error should be returned (via a socket that is expecting read events). You can create one more socket for sending these messages periodically to detect a peer disappearance (heart beat connection) on the client side. But all this retries might still take some time.

Another option could be to use `SO_KEEPALIVE` socket option. After some time a connection has been idle, TCP starts sending probe messages to the server and can detect its disappearance. The default values for idle item are usually enormously huge, so they need to be modified. Some of other parameters that might be related (TCP_KEEPCNT, TCP_KEEPINTVL, TCP_KEEPIDLE). It appears, this option might be implemented differently on different systems or can be simply absent.

I've never personally tried to solve this problem so all this is just a bunch of thoughts that might give some ideas. Here is one more [source of ideas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37490/Detection-of-Half-Open-Dropped-TCP-IP-Socket-Conne).